Set the cell format in an excel sheet to the general date, without a specific format in python
I want to create an Excel sheet which contains dates. I dont want to specify the date format (like yyyy/mm/dd or the like), but I want Excel to display the dates based on the users locale.
For example, the same excel file opened on a machine with US locale should show dates like mm-dd-yyyy, while opened in say China, it show dates like yyyy-mm-dd.
I realize I can set the cell format to a specific date format, e.g. using openpyxl:
from datetime import datetime

import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import numbers
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet: Worksheet = wb.create_sheet("TEST")


for cell in sheet["C"]:
    cell.number_format = numbers.FORMAT_DATE_DATETIME
    # cell.number_format = numbers.FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYY
    # cell.number_format = "YYYY-MMM-DD"

sheet.cell(column=3, row=1, value=datetime.now())
wb.save("temp.xlsx")

However, this seems to hardcode the format, regardless of locale. The format category excel displays is called "Custom". However, in the excel UI I can also see the category "Date"
Excel Screenshot.
How can I use openpyxl to tell Excel to display a date in the locale of a user?

Because Excel stores datetimes as numbers, you must choose a format to display them as date and times. Locale formats can be set but depend upon the version of Excel installed. As a result, openpyxl uses the ISO format to be as unambiguous as possible.
